# Python, using singleton pattern or just global variable

Tags: python, singleton, global-variables

In python, is it better that using the singleton pattern instead of using global variable?

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' not in self.__dict__:
            self.instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.instance
```

or just make a global variable:

```
SINGLETON_VARIABLE = None
def getSingleton():
    if SINGLETON is None:
        SINGLETON_VARIABLE = SOME_ININ_CLASS()
    return SINGLETON_VARIABLE
```

Is it necessary to complicate the life to make a singleton pattern? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the global variable approach would be that you can always access that variable and modify its content, so it would be a "weaker" form of the Singleton pattern. Also, if you have more than one Singleton class, you have to define a function and a global variable for each, so it ends up being messier than the pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot, any side-effect with singleton approach?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I was a bit overloaded with work and didn't have the extra time to come by. I think the worst the Singleton pattern brings is the extra complexity in the class definition, but that is a price you pay once and then reap the benefits. You seem to have it nailed down already, so I'd just go with it.

Comment: thank you very much for such comprehensive explanation.