# From module import global variable

Tags: python, import, global-variables, python-import, global

Considering this project structure:

```
project
  ...
   |-- view
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- app_view.py
        |-- component.py
```

And these imports and declarations:

```
# __init__.py
from view.app_view import AppView
global APP_VIEW
APP_VIEW = AppView()


# app_view.py
from view.component import Component
class AppView:
    def __init__(self):
        self.component = Component()   


# component.py
from view import APP_VIEW
class Component:
   ...
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'APP_VIEW'

Is the message I've been receiving and I suppose there's something related with the cyclic import structure, but I tried some other organizations without success. So I was wonder how to solve this situation.

1. What is the Pythonic file structure for related modules like this?
2. How should I store a global variable to be able to import it along with the whole project?

Comment: Yes, the problem is your circular import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is, as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, in you circular/cyclic imports. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/6754986) explains how your problem occurs in detail.
[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748946/pythonic-way-to-resolve-circular-import-statements) has a similar problem as you and has a quick fix.

Your file structure is not the problem. However, you could use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), instead of a global variable, in order to archive what you want to do. [Here is a comparison in python projects of these two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429349/python-using-singleton-pattern-or-just-global-variable).